# Collection property for WPF UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, user-interface

I want to create a `UserControl` in WPF through which I want to expose a collection property. I want to change the UI of the `UserControl` based on the changes in collection.

For example, lets say I have a collection of strings which is binded to my `UserControl`. Based on that collection i want to create buttons on the `UserControl` containing those text as button text. Is there a way I can acieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set a `DataTemplate` containing a button for an `ItemsControl` control that is binded to that collection. For Example:

```
//For code:
items.DataContext = new List<string>
{
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3"
};

//For XAML            
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```